# Code Coverage for custom exception

Tags: apex

I have an exception class with unit test as follows but not able to get any code coverage which is holding up the deployment.

Exception Class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {}
```

Unit test:

```
/**
 * Unit test for CustomException class
 */
testmethod static void testCustomException() {

    try{
        throw new CustomException('TestException');
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
    System.assertEquals(0, ApexPages.getMessages().size());
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't even require coverage...please include some more details about your deployment, perhaps a screenshot.

Comment: Attached the error screenshot during deployment.

Comment: Is that your only code in production? I doubt it since it would be if I use. Deploy with running default tests or at least the tests for the classes using the exception.

Comment: Wondering if you are using @isTest in your class.

Comment: That looks like the behavior when you introduce a compile fail. Did any of your classes fail to compile?

Comment: Yes, I'm using @isTest(seeAllData=True). I'm deploying multiple classes and only this exception class is failing with no code coverage error.  All classes compiled successfully.

Comment: Got the issue as I'm trying to validate through "Run the specified" test classes it is throwing the code error but when I try to deploy just this class with "Run All test" option deployed successfully.

Comment: If you don't want this test to fail, you should put the assertEquals inside the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converting commment to answer*

Is that your only code in production? I doubt it since it would be of no use.

I bet you are attempting to deploy with "Specified Tests"

Deploy with running default tests or at least the tests for the classes using the exception.